# fork prints last record twice

Tags: python, multithreading

The code below connects to a db and for every record it finds, it should print a child process.  Right now there are only two records in the db.  It prints the first one and the then the second one gets printed twice. Looking at "work" it prints 1, 2,2.
Not sure why this is happening, please help.

```
 for row in records:
           id = str(row[0])
           phone = str(row[1])

           print work
           work = work + 1

           pid = os.fork()
           if (pid == 0):

               #time.sleep(1)
               #print "Child process " + str(os.getpid()) + str(row[1])
               print "Child process " + str(row[1])
           exit()
           cursor.close()
   #exit()
   #cursor.close()
   #exit()
   print "Parent process -- Child is " + str(pid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the prints that you mention in your question, unless I remove the `exit()` call just before `cursor.close()`. I also needed to remove the `cursor.close()`. At that point, I get the behavior you describe.

Remember that `os.fork()` creates a duplicate process (the child) and continues the original process (the parent). The parent process executes the `for` loop twice (once for each of the two records), so you get the '1' and a '2' output. Meanwhile, the child process executes the second iteration of the `for` loop (the first was already executed, before the `os.fork()`) and prints the second '2'.

In other words, the first iteration of the loop is executed by the parent process before the `os.fork()`. The second iteration of the `for` loop is executed by both the parent and the child processes.

Comment: Below is the output I get when I run the script.  As you can see the last record is being printed twice.  I have already taken out the exit() and the cursor line and does not make a difference.

Comment: 1
Child process 1112223333
2
2
Parent process -- Child is 28458
Child process 4445556666
Parent process -- Child is 0
Parent process -- Child is 28459
Child process 4445556666
Parent process -- Child is 0

Comment: Taking out the `exit()` and `cursor.close()` will not fix the problem. As I said, the problem is `the first iteration of the loop is executed by the parent process before the os.fork(). The second iteration of the for loop is executed by both the parent and the child processes`. To stop the child process from executing the the second iteration, you need to do something like putting a `break` in the `if (pid == 0)` block.